# Use a join or a subquery to select a single column

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery

I'm writing an app that has a chat function and using Postgres as the db.  There are 4 tables involved-  users (holds user data, including their id), groups (holds a list of groups, including groupid), group_users (holds a mapping of groupids to userids, 1 to many), and groupchats (holds a mapping of groupid to the userid who entered the chat and the text itself).  All tables have the obvious foreign keys between them.

I want to get all rows in groupchats that belong to a given groupid.  But I only wish to do so if the person requesting it is in that group.  I also want to get the name of the person talking for each row (remember the row stores the user ids).

The following is what I've come up with.  What I'm curious is if there's a better way?  I'm using a subquery to get the name of the user in the current row.  Should I be using a join instead?  Also, I believe my second subquery (for the exists clause) should only be run once, am I correct in that?  Or would I be better off with that in client side logic (making a 2nd round trip to the db)?  I would expext the DB can optimize this.

```
SELECT userid, chat, time, 
      (SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE id=groupchat.userid) 
FROM groupchat 
WHERE groupid=$1 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT userid 
              from group_users 
              WHERE groupid=$1 AND userid=$2) 
ORDER BY time ASC;
```

Comment: The scalar sub-select in the select list is not necessary a bad thing. Check the execution plan. "*I believe my second subquery (for the exists clause) should only be run once*" - correct because it is not referencing the outer tables (it is *not* a co-related sub-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is fine.  You can write this as an explicit `JOIN`.  Using a correlation also means that you only have to include `$1` once in the query:

```
SELECT gc.userid, gc.chat, gc.time, u.firstname
FROM groupchat gc JOIN
     users u
     ON u.id = gc.userid
WHERE gc.groupid = $1 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM group_users fu
              WHERE gu.groupid = gc.groupid AND gu.userid = $2
             ) 
ORDER BY gc.time ASC;
```

If you have a large amount of data, then you would want the following indexes:  `groupchat(groupid, time)`, `users(id, firstname)`, and `group_users(groupid, userid)`.